# Перекрывание нижестоящего блока раскрывающейся частью при наведении

Tags: css3, css

Есть код:

```
.product {position:relative;  background-color: #fff; float:left;width:250px;vertical-align:top; margin:20px; border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;}
.product:hover {border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8); outline: 0; outline: thin dotted \9;-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);

              }

 бла-бла-бла...

.product .option{position:absolute;top:100%;width:100%;display:none;}
.product:hover .option,.product.active .option{position:relative;display:block;padding-bottom:0}
```

Если этих блоков много они выстраиваются друг за другом, слева на право, допустим 3 сверху и 3 снизу. Нужно чтобы при наведении курсора на блок, появившаяся часть option перекрывала низ стоящий блок т.е. поверх нижестоящего блока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hzdh7/ оно?

З.Ы. Прошу простить что в коде не использовал Ваш CSS

Comment: Нет, это похоже, на то что мне нужно, но все же не то!